How to make request to nginx server_name in kubernetes
I have deployed nginx in my kubernetes cluster with this configmap:
apiVersion: v1
data:
  json.conf: |-
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name api.test.com;
      location / {
        proxy_pass https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
      }
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: json
  namespace: app

My problem is when I want to request this nginx pod from another pod, I have to call the nginx pod's service in Kubernetes but I want to call for example http://api.test.com in my request. How can handle this?
I have tried this in (for example in api-app-chart-f5bbcf55d-fthbz):
curl http://nginx-egress-app-chart-svc-web

But i want to request like this:
curl http://api.test.com


that comes down to dns

Do you have any idea or solution? @DanielA.White

How about ingress? probably this gonna help you to understand https://pjausovec.medium.com/expose-your-kubernetes-service-from-your-own-custom-domains-cc8a1d965fc

Actually i want to call my nginx pod internally, not from the outside. @ChachatonelHashimotto

then you can directly call the nginx service, but if you want only host api.test.com to be accepted and routed by nginx then use host header "host: api.test.com" in the request

You can implement it with rewrite feature of CoreDNS.
Add this line to CoreDNS config file. (NOTE: replace <namespace>)
rewrite name api.test.com nginx-egress-app-chart-svc-web.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local

.:53 {
    errors
    health  {
        lameduck 5s
    }
    rewrite name api.test.com nginx-egress-app-chart-svc-web.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
    ready 
    kubernetes   cluster.local  cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
        pods insecure
        fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        ttl 30
    }
    prometheus   0.0.0.0:9153
    forward   . /etc/resolv.conf
    cache   30
    loop 
    reload 
    loadbalance 
}

At the end rollout your CoreDNS to apply the changes.

Awesome! That is exactly what i wanted. Thanks a lot ^=^.
